# How to retrieve a list of contacts that belong to a specific group without limit error

Tags: google-people-api

I am unable to read contacts of a group.

I use the method contactGroups.List (https://people.googleapis.com/v1/contactGroups) to read all groups.

Then I read all the contacts with the supplied resource names for the given group with the people.get method (https://people.googleapis.com/v1/resourceName).

This works, but since a request is required for every contact, I immediately get the error:

Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit 'Read requests per minute per user' of service 'people.googleapis.com' for consumer.

The limit is 75 requests / 60s / user.

Is there another way?

Comment: Which endpoint are you using when you hit the read request limit, and what/how many requests have you made at the point of failure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [google people.api, how to get members of a specific group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937357/google-people-api-how-to-get-members-of-a-specific-group)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your request with a try/catch and repeat the call after 2sec if a HttpError with code 429 (limit reached) is raised.

I'm not sure what language you are using so here is something generic.

```
Function my_call(request):
    Try:
        Return request.execute()
    Catch HttpError as error:
        If error.resp.status == 429:
            sleep(2sec)
            Return my_call(request)
        Else:
            Raise error
```

Where the request is built by the people.get method and the HttpError can be included from the googleapi module/library I believe.

Note that it would probably be more efficient (API calls wise) to use the people.connection.list method and retrieve 
the contacts from the response instead.

Comment: people.connection.list function not for groups

Comment: The groups from contactGroup.list each have a group.resourceName an a list of contact resourceNames. The contacts from people.connection.list each have a contact.resourceName and a list of contactGroups with a contactGroupResourceName. You can put the two in relation (ex. with dicts), it's a little more work but you go from (groups * group.members) API calls to 2 calls. If you need an exemple I could add one to my answer at some point.

Comment: i think the right way is the one in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937357/google-people-api-how-to-get-members-of-a-specific-group

Comment: Indeed it is, seems like I missed it. Since this question has already been answered (although later) I'll *flag it as duplicate.