# Google people.api, how to get members of a specific group?

Tags: google-people-api

With people.api I can only read the people in the main group, with people.connections.list:

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/Me/connections
```

with MS REST.api I can also read the people in a sub-group

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contactfolders/{contact_folder_id}/contact
```

I know that I can use contactGroups.get to find the resource names. But then I need one people.get request for each resource name.

Unfortunately, this is not possible because the maximum number of allowed requests will then be exceeded very quickly (75 / min).

So what's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can use the `people.getBatchGet` end point to make a batch request to the API and get multiple resources in one request.*

#### More Information:

After using the `contactGroups.get` call to get the resource IDs you can use the batch request method to get multiple responses at once. Using:

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:batchGet
```

as your endpoint, and specifying which `personFields` you wish to get from the `resourceNames`.

You can test it on the **Try This API** feature of `people.getBatchGet` [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet). Each `resourceName` is in the form `people/cXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` which you obtain from the `contactGroups.get` response.

Please note, as per the documentation:

> You can include up to 50 resource names in one request.

#### Example resource:

```json
{
  "personFields": "emailAddresses",
  "resourceNames": [
    "people/c1111111111111111111",
    "people/c2222222222222222222",
    "people/c3333333333333333333"
  ]
}
```

#### References:

- [People API - `contactGroups.get` method](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/get)
- [People API - `people.getBatchGet` method](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet)

Comment: Thank you very much!
But, how many resourceNames can I put in one people.batchGet ???

Comment: an other question: How do I build the resourceNames string (how are the resources separated)?

Comment: This depends on your implementation, but the JSON structure is  an array inside the request resource - I've put a sample in my answer now.

Comment: I missed the comma, thx. A general question: Are there any groups in Google at all? When I call up my contacts I don't see groups but labels. And even if I create a contact under a label, it exists under MyContacts. The values under the labels are only pointers to the actual contact.

Comment: Groups are used, see [contactGroups overview](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups). They do not work in the same way as Outlook though and people are **always** separate from groups. You can actually get a better idea of how they work from the [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact-group).

Comment: I get the error Code 400: Person resource name "people/c864590510507160885,people/c1546047072727163997" must be in the format "people/<person_id>".

Comment: Each `people/cXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` needs to be in quotes, then comma separated. like `"people/c1111111111111111111", "people/c2222222222222222222","people/c3333333333333333333"` etc

Comment: i use the resourceName parm in my HTTP request:  web_HTTP.Open "GET", web_Url_AllResources & "?" & _
        "access_token=" & Token & "&" & _
        "key=" & ApiKey & "&" & _
        "resourceNames=" & resources(1) & "&" & _
        "personFields=" & "names,addresses,organizations,memberships" I can't use Quotes. With one resource it works fine. I don't know to define more then one.

Comment: Considering the scope and complexity of the issues you're having, I'm struggling to understand where the underlying problem lies. If you could, please accept the answer here that addressed your original question and ask a new question with the code that you're trying in order to address your new issue as it's difficult to properly understand with the limited structure of comments.

Comment: be sure to specify maxMembers or the response won't include any!