# With the Contacts API Migrating to the People API, how can I get a list of contacts with a specific label?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I was getting a list of contacts using the Contact method in Google App Script. As of June 16th, the Contact method is not longer available.  I am trying to use the People method but cannot figure out how to get a specific list of email addresses categorized by the label.  Please help and TYIA

Original Google App Script:

```js
    var emailList = [];
    var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Membership Committee').getContacts();

    for(var i in contacts){
      emailList.push(contacts[i].getEmailAddresses());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered by [Rafa Guillermo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59946028/14606052):

1. Use `contactGroups.get` to get the group member resource names.
2. Use `people.getBatchGet` to make a batch request to the API and use member resource names and `personFields: 'emailAddresses'` as parameters.

**Example:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var groupId = "Insert Group/Label ID here"
  var contactGroup = People.ContactGroups.get('contactGroups/'+groupId, {"maxMembers" : 50});
  var memberResourceNames = contactGroup.memberResourceNames;
  var test = People.People.getBatchGet({
    resourceNames: memberResourceNames,
    personFields: 'emailAddresses'
  })

  test.responses.forEach(res => {
    Logger.log(res.person.emailAddresses[0].value);
  })
}
```

*Note:* Label ID can be found by clicking a **Label** and in the URL, any characters after `https://contacts.google.com/label/` is the ID.

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [Method: contactGroups.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/get)
- [Method: people.getBatchGet](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet)